# Requirejs using shim

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

Using shim by requirejs2, there is a way to tell to requires that a module is already loaded?

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="undescrore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="require.js'"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require.config({
        paths: {
            "backbone": '/vendor/js/backbone-min.js'
        },
        shim: {
            'backbone': {
                //These script dependencies should be loaded before loading
                //backbone.js
                deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'], // here I would like to load the already loaded library
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 23):

Well, if underscore is already loaded and available, you do not need the shim at all. Backbone will happily load. If not, it's probably because underscore is *not* actually loaded.

It sounds however wrong to be only partially using require.js, you might as well AMD-load them all. To do that you will need to change your shim like this:

```
shim: {
    backbone: {
        deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
        exports: "Backbone"
    },

    underscore: {
        exports: "_"
    }
}
```

and of course update your `paths`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you were able to find the best approach yet for your use case.
If you really - for some reason - need to add your other scripts without using RequireJS as in your code example @js999, then you would need to check if the global variable (jQuery, _) of those scripts exist and then define them as modules. From your code example it would look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="undescrore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="require.js'"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // check for jQuery 
    if (window.jQuery) {
        define('jquery', [], function () {
            return window.jQuery;
        });
    }

    // check for underscore
    if (window._) {
        define('underscore', [], function () {
            return window._;
        });
    }

    require.config({
        paths: {
            // remove the file extension (.js)          
            "backbone": '/vendor/js/backbone-min'
        },
        shim: {
            'backbone': {
                deps: ['underscore', 'jquery']
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```