# How do I ensure that modules wait until their dependencies load in require.js?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have about 3 different errors that can occur while loading the same page. I get different errors when I refresh the same page: jquery ui loads before jquery, or underscore does not load in time to be a dependency. Is there a way to make sure the configuration modules wait until their depenedencies load before loading themselves? I am using the following:

main.js

```
require.config({
paths: {
    jQuery: 'libs/jquery/jquery-wrapper',
    Underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore-wrapper',
    Backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone-wrapper',
}
});
require([
'src/app',
'order!libs/jquery/jquery-min',
'order!libs/jquery/jquery-ui-min',
'order!libs/jquery/jquery.ui.selectmenu',
'order!libs/underscore/underscore-min',
'order!libs/backbone/backbone-min',
], function (App) {
App.initialize();
 });
```

I grab injected dependencies from the page. 
app.js

```
define([
    'jQuery',
    'src/global'
], function ($) {

var initialize = function () {
    var d = $('#dependencies').html();
    require($.trim($('#dependencies').html().toString()).split(','), function () {
    });
}

return {
    initialize: initialize
};
```

});

Comment: I have the same problem. I have scripts with self executing functions and loading them with requires causes many undefined errors

Comment: you can find answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802961/requirejs-using-shim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to Require 2.0 and employed a shim that is working for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Require v2, which got rid of order. I switched back to version 1 and the problem was resolved.